# Out of index for os.walk

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `os.walk` to recursively go through a directory and print only the first file inside the directory.

The folder structure looks like this

```
   Project_Folder
    ├── Case001
    │   └── asdf422345112323423
    │       └── puppy.txt
    ├── Case002
    │   ├── jjasdfjtnqn3881847471
    │   │   └── apple.txt
    │   └── jtnjjqjqjwkwktjjthqj
    │       └── banana.txt
    └── Case003
        └── asdfasdfntjejqk21244
            ├── herwerhqkethf4443434
            │   ├── orange.txt
            │   └── cow.txt
            └── jdjdjafjejqjqyttjdjak
                └── cat.txt
```

and the code I'm using is

```
import os

rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print(fileList[0])  # I only want the first file
```

But I keep getting an "list index out of range" error. However, I know from getting rid of the index and just doing `print(fileList)` that multiple lists are printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably no files in certain directories. Try the following:

```
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    if fileList:
        print(fileList[0])  # I only want the first file
```

(The if-test evaluates to `False` if the list is empty)